# Two Parts, Three Lines, Five Words

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, word-property

### The Puzzle

Property reserved indisputably. Mystery expecting.

Nearly unbelievable! Most buzzwords excluded ruthlessly! So?

Ass subs cons, cost leg.

### OP's Words

This puzzle may be too vague, or perhaps not. Hints would be given when needed.

Comment: rot13(Gur npebfgvpf fcryy Cevzr Ahzoref NFPVV rqvg:NFFPY ohg V'z abg fher jung qb jvgu vg :))

Comment: @Zoir Not NFPVV ...

Comment: @Zoir Yeah, I noticed the same thing, but the last part doesn't quite work... I'm not sure how to parse it or what to do with it.

Comment: Mistake , NFPPY :)

Comment: @Deusovi The last part is rot13(svir jbeqf zvffvat 'HZR' sebz gur raq - NFFHZR, FHOFHZR, PBAFHZR, PBFGHZR, YRTHZR...) - but again, not sure where that leads just yet...

Comment: @Stiv That could be worth posting as an answer, since it's surely not a coincidence. Considering the numerical values of the new letters might (?) be the connection with the hint you found.

Comment: Thanks @RandalThor - think I've spotted the link with the acrostic too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After encouragement to post by others in comments, perhaps this is the answer you're looking for?

*Property reserved indisputably. Mystery expecting.*
*Nearly unbelievable! Most buzzwords excluded ruthlessly! So?*

These first two lines are:

> An acrostic, spelling **PRIME NUMBERS**.

*Ass subs cons, cost leg.*

These five words:

> Can all be followed by '**UMES**' to make new words: ASSUMES, SUBSUMES, CONSUMES, COSTUMES and LEGUMES.

Furthermore:

> Considering the positions of the letters U, M, E and S as they appear in the word 'N**UM**B**E**R**S**' we are looking at the letters in the **prime number positions**: 2, 3, 5 and 7, thereby fulfilling the acrostic.

Comment: Then, in that case, the five words could be followed by 'UMES' as well, Couldn't they?

Comment: @Quark-epoch That would be much clearer to explain, wouldn't it! Will edt for clarity...